# Should a REST service expose a XSD for XML responses?

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, xsd

We've build a REST service that depending on the accept header will return XML or JSON to the client, or depending the content-type header will accept XML or JSON.

Now a recent integrator asked us whether we have a XSD schema for our XML responses and requests.

Is this a common practice to have when developing REST services?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is absolutely common practice to provide callers of any service, including REST, with some form of definition of the interface for that service.  If you have an XML interface, an XML schema of some sort ([XSD](http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/schema), [RELAX NG](http://relaxng.org/), [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/), etc) is a fine way to define the **request** *and* **response** interface.  In addition to providing documentation, it can be used by validating parsers to catch violations of the declared interface.

You might also consider creating [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) definitions of your JSON interface.  It can provide some of the same benefits as an XML schema would, however it arguably is less "common practice" than XML schemas are for XML.

Comment: Is JSON Schema spec actually finalized? Is it used extensively? Another thing I came across for REST was RAML (http://raml.org/).

Comment: Good questions.  I'm currently cautioning clients that the latest [IETF JSON Schema spec, v4](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html), expired in August 2013 and that those who use JSON rarely use JSON Schema.

Answer (score 7):

The previous answers are correct, that this is *common* practice.

However, I suggest that is not *good* practice.

The bad thing about using an xsd to validate a response, is the close binding that you create between the client and server. Ideally, a client would follow the tolerant reader pattern (see, eg, http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TolerantReader.html). The client should only require the data that it needs, and not fail unnecessarily. So if the server was to start sending extra data, or fail to send unneeded data, the client should be able to continue without complaint. The client's domain model should represent only the data the client actually needs.

Back in the old days of SOAP, this tight binding between client and server was accepted as ok, or even good, and enforced in the wsdl and xsd. REST architectures should be promoting loose coupling instead, and allowing services to evolve with as little impact as possible.

Using the xsd to validate a response is good only in rare situations. For example, when the service will never change (it might be a throwaway service to do once-off data migration), or when you think it is ok to have the client and server domain models tightly bound (I think this is ok for unit tests). An argument could be made for publishing the xsd once a service is stable, but I think this a very hard call to make.

(and even though this is still common practice, I'm finding that it is not as common as it was. I was talking to an architect at a large government agency last week, and their standard is to only use xpath to obtain data from xml responses, and never use domain objects based on an xsd)

Comment: -1 for attacking a [**straw man**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man).  You say "it is not good practice," but the ***it*** that I [referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27110734/290085) was ***"some form of definition of the interface for that service"***, not "*using an xsd to generate domain objects,*" or "*using the xsd to generate client good [sic].*"

Comment: Thanks for that point - it is a good one. I've removed any reference to generating domain objects, since it wasn't mentioned in your answer. I included domain objects as another example of tight coupling between client and server, that we all see quite often. I thought it was interesting and relevant in the context, but it was a digression. I've also toned my answer down a little, since I can see now how it could give offence.

Comment: The weakness of your argument persists beyond your minor edits.  You conflate tight coupling (bad thing) with contract definition and adherence (good things) and somehow feel justified in proclaiming that contract definition and adherence are therefore bad things.  100% wrong.   **Loose coupling does not mean avoiding interface definition; it means avoiding dependencies between implementations.**   I hope I've helped advance your understanding in this area, but, regardless, I'll be disengaging at this point.  Good luck.

Comment: Contract definition and adherence are good things. Robust clients, that might be able to continue even if the contract changes (or if the publisher fails to adhere), are not a contradiction of this, and are also good things. Suggesting that a client validate the response it receives with an xsd is the opposite of this permissive approach. However, it makes a lot of sense to validate _before sending_ a request or response - this is sensible, and is not related to the _tolerant reader_ pattern.
Thanks for your comment and all the best to you too.

Answer (score 2):

Why not? If you are communicating via XML then you can add `schemaLocation` attribute to specify your schema URL. Otherwise how client can validate server XML and form its own requests properly?